# Using Notepad++ Search all files with a specific pattern

Tags: notepad++

In the Notepad   Find in Files dialog, there is a box for filter.  Normally you would enter something like *.txt in there.  Are there more advanced ways to use the filter?  Specifically, I am looking for the following functionality:  Search all files with a specific pattern not extensions..

Comment: What do you mean by "pattern not extensions"? Can you provide an example?

Comment: You can also use regular expressions with the find dialog.

Comment: pattern means files with  almost similar names,,,, extensions is like .xml,or .txt

Answer (score 1):

The functionality I believe you're looking for can be used by enabling the "Regular Expressions" radio button. It enables you, for instance, to take a list of files written as such:

```
random words.txt
holy monkeys.jpg
foo bar.extension
```

and turn it into

```
words.txt
monkeys.jpg
bar.extension
```

using a simple but not-very-legible system of regular expressions. That's just one example of a "pattern" that you can use, it has an open field of uses that a programmer's mind revels in.

I don't know enough to tell you what to write as a regular expression, but this is points you in the proper direction, I hope.

Best of luck.